# Hide url in anchor tag

Tags: html, asp.net

[abcv](http://ipaddress/uplodfiles/2/abc.jpg)

If i click this it's showing complete address. Problem is the path is shared and anyone can hack this path. Is there any way to not to show this entire path and only show abc.jpg in browser.

Answer (score 1):

You may use following approaches

1. Store the images in the database and use **HttpHandler** to retrieve and display them.
   As additional precaution you may pass current DateTime as encrypted url parameter to verify whether it is a fresh request within a specific time period say 10 minutes. You may refer this article for reference to HttpModule implementation
   [display-images-from-database-in-gridview-in-aspnet-using-handler-ashx-file-in-csharp-vbnet](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2015/07/display-images-from-database-in-gridview-in-aspnet-using-handler-ashx-file-in-csharp-vbnet.html)
2. As another approach you may implement the concept of **Temporary URLs** as described here [Generating Temporary Download URLs](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/a22aaa2f-1c0a-41ba-98bf-faf3351e2f91.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No. The complete path has to be shown so that browsers can retrieve the file.

You could implement a custom HTTP Handler or asp.net page that takes the name of the file in the query string and returns the contents of the file, perhaps even using a unique id (number, guid, etc,...) to map to each file to stop people "guessing" what other valid filenames may be. So, you'd have:

```
http://ipaddress/RetrieveUploadFile.aspx?fileid=36281
```

instead of

```
http://ipaddress/uplodfiles/2/abc.jpg
```

Comment: then how to handle from hacking situation?

Comment: @sreejaya, I've updated my post to show an example of serving the files using a HTTP Handler / custom page. The handler/page could check the user making the request to confirm they're permitted access to the requested file (assuming that the site you're working on involves users logging in).

Comment: This path is in achor tag  html

Comment: @sreejaya, so? There is *no* way to not have some form of URL behind the anchor tag. My suggestion is that you use some form of custom handler (examples I've given are an aspx page or an HTTP Handler) to act as indirection and "hide" the *true* path to the file from end users.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't want to "hide URL"; the whole notion would not make any sense, because all HTTP requests go with some URL. What you want is called URL [rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine):

Please refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) and [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) links