# Hide or encrypt file path (src)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web

I'm developing a music website where local artists can upload their music for everyone to listen to or download. the file path for the songs are stored on a database. I'm using an HTML5 control to play the songs. The one thing that I'm struggling to do is to hide the file path(view page source) of the songs. Some songs will be available for download but the file path shouldn't show in this case as well, this will allow for accurate download audits. Please assist. I'm using ASP.Net C#

Comment: Would be useful if you could show your current download mechanism

Comment: when you are saving the path in database you should encrypt it and when you are using music file you have to decrypt it

Answer (score 0):

You can have the basic idea from the following SO post [Hide url in anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33087902/5104101)

As you are already using a database to store filenames you could leverage the concepts mentioned in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it’s impossible to protect download if you can play it.

If users can play the song, they can download it also. (Because they need to download it in order to play it)

And if you encrypt the path, users will always see the unencrypted path (in order to use it for playing)

So, you just enter in the common problematic of all music website.